# Appending duplicates as columns and removing the other rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with some repeated IDs, like this:

```
index    ID    name    surname
1        1     a       x
2        2     b       y
3        1     c       z
4        3     d       j
```

I'd like to append the columns of the repeated rows to the right and to remove the "single" rows, like this:

```
index    ID    name   surname   second_name   second_surname
1        1     a      x         c             z
```

What is the most efficient way to do it? (I have many millions of rows)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) like so:

```
df['second_name'] = (df.drop_duplicates(subset='ID')
                     .reset_index()
                     .merge(df, on='ID', how='inner', suffixes=('', '_'))
                     .query("name != name_")
                     .set_index('level_0')['name_'])
```

[out]

```
   index  ID name second_name
0      1   1    a           c
1      2   2    b         NaN
2      3   1    c         NaN
3      4   3    d         NaN
```

---

If you only need the single row, use [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df.dropna(subset=['second_name'])
```

[out]

```
   index  ID name second_name
0      1   1    a           c
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion involves groupby and should work for an arbitrary number of "additional" names:

```
df_in = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 1, 3], 'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

grp = df_in.groupby('ID', as_index=True)
df_a = grp.first()
df_b = grp['name'].unique().apply(pd.Series).rename(columns = lambda x: 'name_{:.0f}'.format(x+1)).drop('name_1', axis=1)
df_out = df_a.merge(df_b, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True).reset_index(drop=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to pivot the dataframe. For that, I will first add a rank column to give the rank of a name for its ID:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()
pivoted = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='rank', values='name')
```

giving:

```
rank  0    1
ID          
1     a    c
2     b  NaN
3     d  NaN
```

Let us just format it:

```
pivoted = pivoted.rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename(lambda x: 'name_{}'.format(x),
                                                    axis=1).reset_index()

   ID name_0 name_1
0   1      a      c
1   2      b    NaN
2   3      d    NaN
```

Comment: This is my favorite answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Numpy / Pandas

```
r, i = np.unique(df.ID, return_inverse=True)
j = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()

names = np.empty((len(r), j.max() + 1), object)
names.fill(np.nan)
names[i, j] = df.name

pd.DataFrame(names, r).rename_axis('ID').add_prefix('name_')

   name_0 name_1
ID              
1       a      c
2       b    NaN
3       d    NaN
```

---

#### Loopy

```
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

c = defaultdict(count)
d = defaultdict(dict)

for i, n in zip(df.ID, df.name):
    d[f'name_{next(c[i])}'][i] = n

pd.DataFrame(d).rename_axis('ID')

   name_0 name_1
ID              
1       a      c
2       b    NaN
3       d    NaN
```